# latitude/longitude meta_query

Tags: meta-query

I've been trying to figure out a way to do radius search in WP and decided upon a simpler way than big queries, I'm having problems returning results though

I've got a function called bar_get_nearby() that calculates the latitude/longitude max/min for a given postcode, so that I can then find all entries inside that max/min value.

```
// GET POSTCODES LAT/LNG
$geo = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$_POST['location'].'&sensor=false');
$decode = json_decode($geo);
$latlon = $decode->results[0]->geometry->location->lat.','.$decode->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
$dist = bar_get_nearby($decode->results[0]->geometry->location->lat, $decode->results[0]->geometry->location->lng);

// CHECK THEY WORK
echo $dist['max_latitude'].','.$dist['min_latitude'].'<--<br />';
echo $dist['max_longitude'].','.$dist['min_longitude'].'<---<br />';

// CREATE META QUERIES
$location_LAT = array('key' => 'latitude', 'value' => $dist['max_latitude'], 'compare' => '>=');
$location_LAT2 = array('key' => 'latitude', 'value' => $dist['min_latitude'], 'compare' => '<=');
$location_LNG = array('key' => 'longitude', 'value' => $dist['max_longitude'], 'compare' => '>=');
$location_LNG2 = array('key' => 'longitude', 'value' => $dist['min_longitude'], 'compare' => '<=');
```

I've also tried

```
$latitude = array('key' => 'latitude', 'value' => array($dist['max_latitude'],$dist['min_latitude']), 'compare' => 'BETWEEN');
$longitude = array('key' => 'longitude', 'value' => array($dist['max_longitude'],$dist['min_longitude']), 'compare' => 'BETWEEN');
```

There is no error and there is no results returned, when I run queries via PHPMyAdmin I do get results.

We then run the query given the above arguments;

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'choirs', 'order' => 'asc', 'orderby' => 'title', 'posts_per_page' => 500,
'meta_query' => array(
$location_LAT,
$location_LAT2,
$location_LNG,
$location_LNG2
));

query_posts($args);
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks, P

Comment: There is no actual query in your code, and only partial argument sets for one.

Comment: Sorry sort of left it out as its not really the important part, the query works fine without the meta_query inside it. Have added it in.

Comment: Switch from using `query_posts` to [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead. That aside, what is the result of your query when you pass it into `var_dump($query)`? Also do you have your debug constant defined in your wp-config file?

Answer (score 1):

In both examples, you are searching between `'max'` and `'min'`, where it should be between `'min'` and `'max'`:

```
array( $dist['max_latitude'], $dist['min_latitude'] )

'value' => $dist['max_latitude'], 'compare' => '>=');
'value' => $dist['min_latitude'], 'compare' => '<=');
```

Both mean:

> "Search for a value that ist greater than max_latitude and less than min_latitude"

Another finding why my own `meta_query` didn't work with geo coordinates: `'type' => 'numeric'` does an `SQL CAST()` to `SIGNED`. This removes all the decimals of the geo coordinates before comparison!

Comment: Thanks for sharing that info. Hint: If you ain't got a real solution, you can check the "community wiki" check box when answering. It's then only meant to share knowledge, but don't give or take reputation points when up/downvoting.